# Is there any way to use special characters inside a regex set?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python, and right now I would like something to match up until a space or the end of the string, so I had the regex `".*?[ $]"`.

But after testing that and seeing it didn't work I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and found that special characters lose their special meaning inside sets.

Is there a way to put this meaning back into the set?

Comment: Nope -```Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets. ```.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: What if there was a string with one character - a space? What if a string were empty?

Comment: @wwii Thanks, that's exactly what I was wondering. (Though the answers do help me with my problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, special meaning cannot be put back into the set, so the regex has to be rewritten.

I ended up using the following regex: `.*?(?:\s|$)` which was a combination of different answers.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you regex is incorrect,your regex will match `.*?`+space or character `$` literally.(Note that every regex character except `]` within character class will be escaped)

Instead you can use a positive look ahead :

```
.*(?= |$)
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/sF3qU1/1

Answer (score 2):

I think that for your purpose a word anchor would be sufficient. From `re` internal documentation (run `pydoc re` if you use an Unix-like system):

```
\b       Matches the empty string, but only at the start or end of a word.
```

So, your regex would look like:

```
".*?\\b"
```

or

```
r".*?\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
a = "testing for fun"

    n = match('[^\s]+',a)

>> testing
```